# Fit a circle to a region of an image

Tags: image-processing, fitting, image

I would like to develop a routine that associates a size with images such as that below. My idea is to find the radius of the circle (centered at the origin) that contains (say) 95% of the total density. How can I achieve this? Also, are there better image processing techniques for associating a size to this region?

Date file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vkv7ic3o1e3fnk/data3.dat?dl=0

[image]

Comment: This site is about the software Wolfram Mathematica and not image processing. You might want to consider asking this somewhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `img` is your image, you can use `Binarize` to find a fixed 
fraction of black pixels:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/T76kp.png"];
bin = Binarize[img, Method -> {"BlackFraction", .1}]
```

[image]

Then you can use `ComponentMeasurements` to find the centroid and radius:

```
comp = ComponentMeasurements[
   ColorNegate@bin, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", 
    "Circularity"}, #Circularity > 0.5 &];

HighlightImage[img, {comp /. (index_ -> {c_, r_, __}) :> 
    Circle[c, r]}]
```

[image]

---

**Response to comment:**

@anderstood asked why `ComponentMeasurements` finds two components. We can use the `Mask` measurement to get a binary mask for each component:

```
HighlightImage[img, Image[#]] & /@ 
 ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate@bin, "Mask"][[All, 2]]
```

[image]

and see that the first component is the black border around the image.

Comment: That was blisteringly fast. Thanks! I'll have a play :)

Comment: Why did you use `ColorNegate`? Also, would you know why `ComponentMeasurements[bin, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]` returns _two_ circles (also with `ColorNegate@bin` instead of `bin`)?

Comment: @anderstood: I used `ColorNegate` because `ComponentMeasurements` searches for white objects on a black background - and the source image is the opposite. The second object is the black border around the image.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your data in more detail. The image has a black frame around it which is taken into account! This means, that binarizing using `"BlackFraction"` as Niki did will lead to an incorrect result.

In fact, if you take this into account, then the frame alone contains more than 5% of your total density. Let's calculate the amount of density we want:

```
img = RemoveAlphaChannel[
   ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/T76kp.png"], 
    "Grayscale"]];
data = ImageData[ColorNegate[img], "Real"];
thresh = .95*Total[Flatten[data]]

(* 5539.33 *)
```

By removing only the frame, we are well below this threshold

```
Total[Flatten[ArrayPad[data, -10]]]
(* 4972.88 *)
```

Let us remove this and calculate the 95% boundary correctly

```
data = ArrayPad[data, -10];
thresh = .95*Total[Flatten[data]]
(* 4724.23 *)
```

To create a centered disk that we can use as a mask, we can use `DiskMatrix`. This can be used with varying radii until we find the correct one that meets the wanted threshold:

```
densityDifference[r_?NumericQ] := 
 Total[Flatten[data*DiskMatrix[r, Dimensions[data]]]] - thresh
FindRoot[densityDifference[r], {r, 50, 100}, Method -> "Secant"]
(* about 69 *)

HighlightImage[
 img,
 Image@DiskMatrix[69, Reverse@ImageDimensions[img]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]